# How to Implement Backward (Top Down) Connections

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

Artificial neural nets often use residual (or skip) connections. They look something like this:

```
l1 = layer1(input)
l2 = layer2(l1)
l3 = layer3(l2) + l1
```

Is there a way to reverse this? Here's what I mean:

```
l1 = layer1(input) + l3
l2 = layer2(l1)
l3 = layer3(l2)
```

Biological neural nets have such feedback loops. It would be interesting to implement something like this and test it to see how it performs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just in case you are not familiar: a [Recurrent neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network) seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm very familiar with recurrent nets. They have feedback loops between timesteps in a timeseries. I'm wondering how to (efficiently) implement this between layers (i.e., reverse residual connections). I've never seen an example of it.

Comment: What's the difference? You can start of with some random `l1`, compute `l3`, use it to recompute `l1`, then recompute `l3`, and so on. So isn't it is exactly the same as having multiple time steps? Or am I misunderstanding your point?